# Headers sent on one server, but not on the other

Tags: php

I have two servers. One development server where I develop my code and one live server.

**Live server**
Apache 2.2.23
DirectAdmin 1.43.3
Exim 4.80.1
MySQL 5.1.66
Named 9.7.3
ProFTPd 1.3.4d
sshd
dovecot 2.1.10
Php 5.2.17
SSL certificate

**Dev server**
Apache 2.2.26
DirectAdmin 1.44.3
Exim 4.82
MySQL 5.6.15
Named 9.8.2rc1
ProFTPd 1.3.4d
sshd
dovecot 2.2.10
Php 5.2.17
I know my versions are not up to date, but right now I don't have the opportunity to update this.

The code of my website is exactly the same on both servers except for the site root and database settings (password, username etc). My live server has a SSL certificate.

For some reason on my live server I'm getting the "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error when I want to redirect. This problem didn't occur at all on my development server.

How can this be happening? There could be some whitespace, but why does this only happen on one server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont ignore errors, @amenadiel - You are a very worst programmer.

Stick to the **IPO principle**:

- Input
- Processing
- Output

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_Model

Your problem is, you processing some data AFTER the Output.

Comment: You're right. I wrote my processor before my output and ofcourse it worked fine. Just happen to find it weird that it only occurred on one server.

Comment: I don't ignore them @Adrian Preuß, I just advise not to print them on screen. The developer must check the log files, but allowing the public to see the raw errors on screen is a **major security hole**.

Answer (score -1):

Set php display_errors to Off to avoid that message.

Afterwards, check your php error log to see any notices or warnings that cause those headers to be sent in advance. It seems as if your error level is less tolerant in production, therefore you are triggering notices or warnings you don't see in dev.

Anyway, you shouldn't display errors in production, so it's always a good practice to keep them off.